# find unique data between two values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to QUICKLY find the indices of unique values (epoch Times in this case) between two values, only return all the values between minVal, maxVal (but not twice)  A simplified example is below:

```
import numpy as np 
minVal = 198000  
maxVal = 230000
uniqueExample = np.arange(300, dtype=float) # this is how it expected to exist
# this is how it actually exists, a small repeated values randomly interspersed  
example = np.insert(uniqueExample, 200, np.arange(200,210.))*1000 # *1000 to differentiate from the indices


# now begin process of isolating 
mask = (example < maxVal) & (example > minVal)
idx = np.argwhere(mask).squeeze()
```

## This will return the undesired result of

```
array([199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211,
   212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224,
   225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237,
   238, 239])
```

## To improve the results the following was added

```
 # this was 
if len(set(example[idx])) != len(example[idx]):
    dupes = np.array([x for n, x in enumerate(example[idx]) if x in example[idx][:n]]).squeeze()
    idx = np.delete(idx, np.nonzero(np.in1d(example[idx], dupes).squeeze()[::2]))
```

## this will return the desired result of

```
array([199, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,
   222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234,
   235, 236, 237, 238, 239])
```

This works ok when retrieving indices O(100), but this is SLOW for larger datasets O(100,000)+ (and sometimes doesn't seem to remove all the duplicates) so I've come up with a few options which seem to still be slow, and I'm hoping that someone can explain what about these are slow or find a better/faster way to do it.  Speed is an issue.

```
import time
# define testing function for test functions below 
def timing(f, n, a):
    print(f.__name__,)
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    for i in r:
        f(a[0],a[1],a[2]); f(a[0],a[1],a[2]); 
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(round(t2-t1, 3))

def gettimeBase(example, minVal, maxVal):
    # this is target (speed and simplicity), but returns duplicates
    mask = (example >= minVal) & (example  < maxVal)
    idx = np.argwhere(mask).squeeze()
    return idx
## now one's that don't return duplicates
def gettime1(example, minVal, maxVal):
    mask = (example >= minVal) & (example < maxVal)
    idx = np.argwhere(mask).squeeze()
    if np.size(idx) == 0:
        idx = None
    if len(set(example[idx])) !=len(example[idx]):
     ## when there are duplicate times on the server
        times, idxUnique = np.unique(example, return_index=True)
        mask2 = (times >= minVal) & (times < maxVal)
        idx2 = np.argwhere(mask2).squeeze()
        idx = idxUnique[idx2].squeeze()
        assert (sorted(set(example[idx])) == example[idx]).all(), 'Data Still have duplicate times'
     return idx

def gettime2(example, minVal, maxVal):
    if len(set(example)) != len(example):
        ## when there are duplicate times on the server
        times, idxUnique = np.unique(example, return_index=True)
        mask2 = (times >= minVal) & (times < maxVal)
        idx2 = np.argwhere(mask2).squeeze()
        idx = idxUnique[idx2].squeeze()
    else:
        mask = (example >= minVal) & (example < maxVal)
        idx = np.argwhere(mask).squeeze()
    if np.size(idx) == 0:
        return None
    assert (sorted(set(example[idx])) == example[idx]).all(), 'Data Still have duplicate times'
    return idx

testdata = (example, minValue, maxValue)
testfuncs = gettimeBase, gettime1, gettime2
for f in testfuncs:
    timing(f, 100, testdata)
```

Test Results are (python 3):

gettimeBase
0.127

gettime1
35.103

gettime2
74.953

Comment: I answered with a slight caveat.  Would you be alright with returning the *first* index of repeated values rather than the last?

Comment: The returned indices, in this case, can refer to either of the duplicate values in example as they are just repeated data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***

#### `numpy.unique`

This option is fast, but it will return the index of the *first* occurence per duplicate, whereas it seems in your question, you are grabbing the *last* index of a duplicate.  This means that the indices returned by this method will not match your desired output, but the values they correspond to will be identical.

```
vals, indices = np.unique(example[mask], return_index=True)
indices + np.argmax(mask)
```

```
array([199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 220, 221,
       222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234,
       235, 236, 237, 238, 239], dtype=int64)
```

And here's the caveat that I mentioned:

```
desired = np.array([199, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,
   222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234,
   235, 236, 237, 238, 239])

np.array_equal(start + idx, desired)
# False

np.array_equal(example[start + idx], example[desired])
# True
```

---

***Option 2***

#### `numpy.unique` + `numpy.flip`

```
f = np.flip(example[mask])
vals, indices = np.unique(f, return_index=True)
final = f.shape[0] - 1 - indices
final + np.argmax(mask)
```

```
array([199, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,
       222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234,
       235, 236, 237, 238, 239], dtype=int64)
```

This actually grabs the last occurence, but adds more overhead:

```
np.array_equal(final + idx[0], desired)
# True
```

---

***Performance*** (I included some setup costs)

```
def chris1(arr, mn, mx):
    mask = (arr < mx) & (arr > mn)
    vals, indices = np.unique(arr[mask], return_index=True)
    return indices + np.argmax(mask)

def chris2(arr, mn, mx):
    mask = (arr < mx) & (arr > mn)
    f = np.flip(arr[mask])
    vals, indices = np.unique(f, return_index=True)
    final = f.shape[0] - 1 - indices
    return final + np.argmax(mask)

def sbfrf(arr, mn, mx):
    mask = (arr < mx) & (arr > mn)
    idx = np.argwhere(mask).squeeze()
    if len(set(example[idx])) != len(example[idx]):
        dupes = np.array([x for n, x in enumerate(example[idx]) if x in example[idx][:n]]).squeeze()
    idx = np.delete(idx, np.nonzero(np.in1d(example[idx], dupes).squeeze()[::2]))
    return idx

In [225]: %timeit chris1(example, 198_000, 230_000)
29.6 µs ± 133 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [226]: %timeit chris2(example, 198_000, 230_000)
36.5 µs ± 98.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [227]: %timeit sbfrf(example, 198_000, 230_000)
463 µs ± 7.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```